# Django admin proper urls inside listview

Tags: django, url, django-admin

My current target is to give users the chance to download CSV files from the admin site of my application.

I successfully managed to create an additional column in the model's list view this way:

```
 def doc_link(self):
    return '<a href="files/%s">%s</a>' % (self.output, self.output)
 doc_link.allow_tags = True
```

This shows the file name and creates the link, but sadly - because it's inside my 'searches' view -  it has an URL:

my_site/my_app/searches/files/13.csv.

This is my problem, I would like to have my files stored in the admin media directory, like this:

http://my_site/media/files/13.csv

Does somebody know how to give url which points "outer" from the model's directory?
Maybe somehow tell Django to use the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX in the link?

I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you answered your own question : )

What's stopping you from using `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` if you want to?

I think it's strange you would use `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` since that's where your admin media lives -- you shouldn't be saving anything there, so maybe more like your `MEDIA_URL`.

```
from django.conf import settings


def doc_link(self):
    return '<a href="%sfiles/%s">%s</a>' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.output, self.output)
 doc_link.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Hi,

This was exactly what I want, I just wasn't aware of I can use settings parameters in the models file.. Many thanks!